# How to use Kotlin anonymous classes as arguments for native JavaScript Functions?

Tags: javascript, interop, kotlin

I am setting up the interop layer for [this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/materials/PointCloudMaterial.js) ThreeJS class and the constructor of the class takes in a object which is used to set the properties.

```
//PointCloudMaterial.js    
THREE.PointCloudMaterial = function ( parameters ) {
    THREE.Material.call( this );
    this.color = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );
    this.map = null;
    this.size = 1;
    this.sizeAttenuation = true;
    this.vertexColors = THREE.NoColors;
    this.fog = true;
    this.setValues( parameters );
};
```

Below is what I would like to be able to do in Kotlin, is it possible to use anomalous objects in should a fashion? I was originally thinking of creating an object equivalent to the possible perimeters to pass in, problem with that is it would override the current values which is not something I want.

```
//Interop Layer
native("THREE.PointCloudMaterial")
public class PointCloudMaterial(parameters: object) { } //This doesn't compile "Type Expected"

//Example usage
var sizeObject = object {
     var size: Double = size
}
PointCloudMaterial(sizeObject);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type safe solution may be look like:

```
native 
val <T> undefined: T = noImpl

class PointCloudMaterialParameters (
   val color: Int = undefined,
   val opacity: Double = undefined,
   //val map: THREE.Texture = undefined,
   val size: Double = undefined,
   //val blending: THREE.NormalBlending = undefined,
   val depthTest: Boolean = undefined,
   val depthWrite: Boolean = undefined,
   val vertexColors: Boolean = undefined,
   val fog: Boolean = undefined
)

fun main(args : Array<String>) {
  println(PointCloudMaterialParameters(size = 2.0))
}

native("THREE.PointCloudMaterial")
public class PointCloudMaterial(parameters: PointCloudMaterialParameters)

//Example usage
PointCloudMaterial(PointCloudMaterialParameters(size = 2.0))
```

Another solution which is shorter, but not type safe is:

```
native("THREE.PointCloudMaterial")
public class PointCloudMaterial(parameters: Any)

//Example usage
PointCloudMaterial(object { val size = 2.0 })
```

P.S. We will try to simplify this case in the future.

Comment: The first isn't really type safe since it allows the construction of a PointCloudMaterialParameters with undefined for non-null values.  In this case, I believe all of the parameters to PointCloudMaterialParameters should all be nullable.

Comment: Though, marking them as nullable is also not correct since the Kotlin static analyzer will see them all as having a value, which means ?. and :? operators won't work.